# How point application to database.php which resides in a non-public folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, config

Now that my app is built I am researching how to secure it. If I place database.php file in a folder outside of the public folder how can I point to it from inside the app? Simply using the include structure is not sufficient since this only goes to the top of the public folder.

```
include '../database.php';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it multiple times `include '../../../../database.php';` each .. represents one parent folder
also you can define full path instead of relative path
like `include '/home/secret_folder/place_of_database/database.php';`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dirname()`. Let's say your folder structure is:

```
public_html/
  index.php
  contact.php
  whatever.php
private/
  database.php
```

In your `public_html` files, you can call:

```
$db_file = dirname( $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] ) . '/private/database.php';
include_once( $db );
```

If `public_html` is your `$_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ]`, `dirname` will give you the folder containing `public_html` and `private`. Then you just need to pass the path to `database.php`.

If it's up another level (or more), you can use `dirname` multiple times:

```
$db_file = dirname( dirname( $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] ) ) . '/private/database.php';
```

This would get you another folder up.

Comment: Thank you. So how safe are files outside of the public folders? Am I only able to access files within the app or can some unauthorized person follow my path to gain access somehow?

Comment: The only way they could get to it outside the document root is if they have direct access to the server, or if you have some ridiculous security vulnerability in your code (like something that would get the file contents and print it to the screen, but you'd hopefully know about that). Otherwise, your credentials are safe like this.

Comment: So that is where I should put config and htaccess files

Comment: That's where you would likely put your config file, assuming it has database and other credentials you want to keep safe. I don't know what's in your .htaccess, but if it's used for custom urls and the like, that would stay in your document root. You shouldn't need a .htaccess in the private folder because it should be protected by your server configuration.

Comment: Joe - I could not get the dirname solution to work, but I was able to get ../../ to work from Shooter & SirNash.

Answer (score 1):

you can use './' to specify the current path of the file you're In 
then use many '../' of it to move between folders and get what file you want to include

Comment: Thank you, Shooter, this actually worked ../../lib/database.php